# Errors When Running Java from Command Prompt

Tags: java, command-line

I am having issues with running a java program from Command Prompt. I have a java file called DataRecover, and I have a second java file that is called Triple. Now, when I run javac Triple.java in Command Prompt, it does what it is supposed to. However, when I run javac DataRecover.java, it comes with this error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DataRecover (wrong name: projectbeng\DataRecover

> DataRecover.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
>      static Triple extractTriples(String str) {
>             ^
>    symbol:   class Triple
>    location: class DataRecover
>   DataRecover.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
>                  Triple triples = extractTriples(line);
>                  ^
>    symbol:   class Triple
>    location: class DataRecover

EDIT: I have included both classes. I have now been able to run the javac command, and there is a CLASS file for each in the proper folder. Now, I need to run the DataRecover file in Command Prompt. When I run "java DataRecover" I get the following error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DataRecover (wrong name: projectbeng\DataRecover)".

```
package projectbeng;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class DataRecover {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Create a Scanner for the user
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter file name to process: ");
    File fileName = new File(sc.nextLine() + ".txt"); //Do not include the .txt extension

    if(!fileName.exists()){ //does not exist
        throw new IOException("File \"" + fileName + "\" not found.");
    }

    System.out.println("\nProcessing file: " + fileName + "\n----------------------------------------");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    int lineCount = 0; //assumes file does not end with a new line character
    int tripleLineCount = 0;
    int tripleCount = 0;
    String line = "";

    //Read data from file
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //has another line in the file
        lineCount++;
        if(!line.equals("")) { //is not a blank line
            Triple triples = extractTriples(line);
            if(triples.getHasTriple()) { //line contains triples
                System.out.println(triples.getTriples());
                tripleLineCount++;
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < triples.getTriples().length(); j++) {
                if(triples.getTriples().charAt(j) == '(') tripleCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    //prints out the summary of the file
    System.out.println("\nSummary\n----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Total lines:              " + lineCount);
    System.out.println("Lines containing triples: " + tripleLineCount);
    System.out.println("Total number of triples:  " + tripleCount);  
}

/*Given a string, returns a Triple with a string containing the triples (if any) and a boolean stating whether
or not it contains a triple.

Assumptions:
1.) If a '-' sign is found, it has been added. If preceeding a number (for example -32), the number is 32 where
    the '-' sign is simply garbage.
2.) If a '.' is found in a number (for example 2.32), the potential integers are 2 and 32 where the '.' is
    garbage.
3.) For part c, if the first valid character found is a letter, this will always be the real triple. It does not
    matter whether or not it is part of a word (for example, if it comes across "Dog a", 'D' will be the triple.)
4.) The strings "<null>", "<cr>", "<lf>", and "<eof>" as well as multi-digit numbers (ex. 32) count as single
    characters. Thus, they cannot be broken up (no garbage in between the characters).
*/
static Triple extractTriples(String str) {     
    /*Grammar:
    Triple is in form (a,b,c) where a is either a non-negative integer or the string "<null>", b is a
        non-negative integer where b <= a (b must be 0 if a is <null>), and c is either an individual letter 
        (upper or lower case), period, colon, semicolon, or one of the three strings "<cr>", "<lf>", or "<eof>".
    state == 0 ==> needs left parenthesis
    state == 1 ==> needs right parenthesis
    state == 2 ==> needs comma
    state == 3 ==> needs a
    state == 4 ==> needs b
    state == 5 ==> needs c
    */
    int state = 0;
    int a = -1;
    int b = -1;
    String triples = "";
    String tempTriples = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) == '.' || str.charAt(i) == ':' || str.charAt(i) == ';' || str.charAt(i) == '<' ||
                (str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z') || (str.charAt(i) >= 'A' && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z')
                || (str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') || str.charAt(i) == ',' ||
                str.charAt(i) == '(' || str.charAt(i) == ')') {
            if(state == 0) {
                if(str.charAt(i) == '(') {
                    tempTriples = str.substring(i, i+1);
                    state = 3;
                }
            }else if(state == 1) {
                if(str.charAt(i) == ')') {
                    triples = triples + tempTriples + str.substring(i, i+1) + "  ";
                    tempTriples = "";
                    state = 0;
                    a = -1;
                    b = -1;
                }
            }else if(state == 2) {
                if(str.charAt(i) == ',') {
                    tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, i+1);
                    if(b != -1) state = 5;
                    else state = 4;
                }
            }else if(state == 3) {
                if(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                    int j = i;
                    while(j < str.length() && str.charAt(j) >= '0' && str.charAt(j) <= '9') j++;
                    a = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, j));
                    i = j - 1;
                    tempTriples = tempTriples + a;
                    state = 2;
                }else if(str.length() > i + 5 && str.substring(i, i+6).equals("<null>")) {
                    a = 0;
                    tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, str.indexOf(">", i)+1);
                    i = str.indexOf(">", i);
                    state = 2;
                }
            }else if(state == 4) {
                if(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                    int j = i;
                    while(j < str.length() && str.charAt(j) >= '0' && str.charAt(j) <= '9') j++;
                    b = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, j));
                    i = j - 1;
                    if(b <= a) {
                        tempTriples = tempTriples + b;
                        state = 2;
                    }else b = -1;
                }
            }else if(state == 5) {
                if(str.charAt(i) == '.' || str.charAt(i) == ':'||(str.charAt(i) <= 'z' && str.charAt(i) >= 'a')
                        || str.charAt(i) == ';' || (str.charAt(i) <= 'Z' && str.charAt(i) >= 'A')) {
                    tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, i+1);
                    state = 1;
                }else if((str.length() > i + 4 && str.substring(i, i+5).equals("<eof>")) ||
                        (str.length() > i + 3 && (str.substring(i, i+4).equals("<cr>") ||
                        str.substring(i, i+4).equals("<lf>")))) {
                    tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, str.indexOf(">", i)+1);
                    i = str.indexOf(">", i);
                    state = 1;
                }else if(str.length() > i + 5 && str.substring(i, i+6).equals("<null>")) {
                    i = str.indexOf(">", i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Triple triple = new Triple(true, triples);
    if(triples.equals("")) triple.setHasTriple(false); //does not contain a triple
    return triple;
}
```

```js
package projectbeng;
class Triple {
    boolean hasTriple = this.hasTriple;
    String triple = this.triple;
    
    //creates a new Triple
    Triple(boolean newHasTriple, String newTriple){
        this.hasTriple = newHasTriple;
        this.triple = newTriple;
    }
     //returns whether or not Triple contains any triples
    boolean getHasTriple() {
        return hasTriple;
    }
    
    //returns the triples in Triple
    String getTriples() {
        return triple;
    }
    
    //changes the state of whether a Triple contains triples
    void setHasTriple(boolean newHasTriple){
        this.hasTriple = newHasTriple;
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to run the DataRecover file through Command Prompt?

Comment: Please post more of your code. We need to see the structure of the code in the file.

Comment: @Blorgbear I have added more code as well as explained my current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are referencing the source files in other files, you have to give all those files together. In your case it should be:

```
javac Triple.java DataRecover.java
```

Many modern Java projects use *build tools* to help with the management of source files. Two popular Java build tools are Gradle and Maven.

Comment: Thank you. That resolved my issue; however, I now have another one. The CLASS files for both DataRecover and Triple are now in the folder, but when I run "java DataRecover" in Command Prompt, it says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DataRecover (wrong name: projectbeng\DataRecover". I seem to be missing something else as well.